# Does any Riccati equation admit local solutions?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is it true that any differential equation of the form:

$$w'(t)=a(t)w^2(t)+b(t)w(t)+c(t),$$

where $a,b,c:[\alpha,\beta]\to\mathbb{R}$ are continuous functions, admit a solution in the neighbourhood of any constant $\gamma\in (\alpha,\beta)$?